# RSpec: How to write unit test case to receive an exception which is getting raised in private method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I have implemented Optimistic Locking for Race Condition. For that, I added an extra column `lock_version` in the Product. Method: `recalculate` is calling private `method_1` then it saves (`save!`) the product. I can't use `save!` in private `method_1`, because it will fail the other things. I don't want to restructure the business logic.

```
#Product: Model's new field:
    #  lock_version                       :integer(4)      default(0), not null

def recalculate
  method_1
  self.save!
end

private
def method_1
    begin
      ####
      ####
      if self.lock_version == Product.find(self.id).lock_version
         Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
      else
         raise ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError.new(self, "test")
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError => e
        if tries < 3
           tries += 1
           sleep(1 + tries)
           self.reload
           retry
        else
           raise Exception.new(timeout.inspect)
        end
    end
end
```

Rspec Test case:

```
  it 'if car is updated then ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError should be raised' do
    prod_v1 =Product.find(@prod.id)
    prod_v2 = Car.find(@prod.id)
    prod_v1.recalculate
    prod_v1.reload  # will make lock_version of prod_v1 to 1

    prod_v2.recalculate # howvever lock_version of prod_v2 is still 0.

    expect(car_v2).to receive(:method1).and_raise(ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError)
  end
```

When I try to write above the test case, then it should raise an Exception `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError`. However, I am getting an error like

```
 Failure/Error: expect(car_v2).to receive(:set_total_and_buckets_used).and_raise(ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError)
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like:

```
expect(ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError).to receive(:new).and_call_original
```

Because you are rescue-ing the exception

Make sure to check https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers

```
expect(car_v2).to receive(:method1).and_raise(ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError)
```

Means that when `car_v2` receives the `method1` you won't call it but you'll raise an exception of type `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError`. This is why you also receive the ArgumentError

With rspec you can check that a specific code raises an error (that is not handled in your case it is handled -> rescue...) like this:

```
expect { my_cool_method }.to raise_error(ErrorClass)
```

Comment: Getting      `ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)`