# Rspec: How to test retry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I have implemented Optimistic Locking for Race Condition. If `lock_version` doesn't match with the updated `lock_version` in the database, then it will trigger `retry` three times. Can you suggest how to test this `retry` event

```
#Product: Model's new field:
    #  lock_version                       :integer(4)      default(0), not null

def recalculate
  method_1
  self.save!
end

private
def method_1
    begin
      ####
      ####
      if self.lock_version == Product.find(self.id).lock_version
         Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
      else
         raise ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError.new(self, "test")
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError => e
        if tries < 3
           tries += 1
           sleep(1 + tries)
           self.reload
           retry
        else
           raise Exception.new(timeout.inspect)
        end
    end
end
```

Rspec Unit Test:

```
  it 'if car is updated then ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError should be raised' do
    prod_v1 =Product.find(@prod.id)
    prod_v2 = Product.find(@prod.id)
    prod_v1.recalculate
    prod_v1.reload  # will make lock_version of prod_v1 to 1
    prod_v2.recalculate # howvever lock_version of prod_v2 is still 0.
    expect{car_v2.send(:method1)}.to receive(:retry)
  end
```

Comment: You could mock the `sleep` method and count check that it is called with successive values 2, 3, 4.

Comment: @WizardofOgz can you suggest how to test successive values 2, 3, 4

Comment: `tries` is not defined in `method_1` (will raise a `NameError`)  and even if I assume it is defined in place of the `######` then it will reset on each `retry` defeating the whole purpose unless you are using `||=` I guess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RSpec: How to write unit test case to receive an exception which is getting raised in private method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640468/rspec-how-to-write-unit-test-case-to-receive-an-exception-which-is-getting-rais)

Answer (score 1):

I would begin by breaking down the complexity of your method1, into something like this.

```
private
def stale_object?
  self.lock_version == Product.find(self.id).lock_version
end

def attempt_to_rescue_stale_object
  if rescue_stale_object_retries =< 3
    rescue_stale_object_retries += 1
    sleep( 1 + rescue_stale_object_retries)
    retry # and the sleep stuff, not sure how you
  else
    raise Exception.new(timeout.inspect)
  end
end

def rescue_stale_object_retries
  @rescue_stale_object_retries ||= 0
end

def method_1
  begin
    raise ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError.new(self, "test") if stale_object?
    Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
  rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError => e
    attempt_to_rescue_stale_object
    reload # You can omit the self here
   else
      raise Exception.new(timeout.inspect)
    end
  end 
end
```

Now you can test it however you like it, the complexity of the rescue logic is wrapped away into a method. You don't depend on testing the actual behaviour in it (that is now a sleep call but it could change into say running a background job).

[https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/receive-counts][1] gives us something like this

```
expect{car_v2}.to receive(:attempt_to_rescue_stale_object).exactly(3).times
car_v2.method1
```

Another benefit of breaking the complexity into small parts is that your intention is better conveyed to your fellow developpers (another person or you 6 months down the road having forgotten about your initial testing goal)

Comment: I am getting error `Invalid retry`. Looks like the Begin/Rescue block is the only way to use Retry now.

Comment: Oh, my bad i treated retry as some pseudocode instead of a key word. It would need a bit of a rework to run properly